# Does Visual Studio Server Explorer support custom database providers?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, oracle, sqlite

I had used Server Explorer and related tools for graphical database development with Microsoft SQL Server in some of my learning projects - and it was a great experience. However, in my work I deal with Oracle DB and SQLite and my hobby projects use MySQL (because they are hosted on Linux).

Is there a way to leverage the database-related tools in Visual Studio with other database providers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is instructions on how to connect to your MySQL database from Visual Studio:

> To make the connection in server
>   explorer you need to do the following:
>
> - first of all you need to install the MyODBC connector 3.51 (or latest) on
>     the development machine (NB. you can
>     find this at
>     http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/odbc/
>     )
> - Create a datasource in Control Panel/Administrative Tools with a
>     connection to your database. This data
>     source is going to be used purely for
>     Server Manager and you dont need to
>     worry about creating the same data
>     source on your clients PC when you
>     have made your VS.NET application
>     (Unless you want to) - I dont want to
>     cover this in this answer, too long.
>     For the purpose of this explanation I
>     will pretend that you created a MyODBC
>     data source called 'AADSN' to database
>     'noddy' on mysqlserver 'SERVER01' and
>     have a root password of 'fred'. The
>     server can be either the Computer Name
>     (found in Control
>     Panel/System/Computer Name), or
>     alternatively it can be the IP
>     Address. NB. Make sure that you test
>     this connection before continuing with
>     this explanation.
> - open your VS.NET project
> - go to server explorer
> - right-click on 'Data Connections'
> - select 'Add Connection'
> - In DataLink Properties, go to the provider tab and select "Microsoft OLE
>     DB Provider For ODBC drivers"
> - Click Next
> - If you previously created an ODBC data source then you could just select
>     that. The disadvantage of this is that
>     when you install your project
>     application on the client machine, the
>     same data source needs to be there. I
>     prefer to use a connection string.
>     This should look something like:
>
> DSN=AADSN;DESC=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver
>   DSN;DATABASE=noddy;SERVER=SERVER01;UID=root;PASSWORD=fred;PORT=3306;SOCKET=;OPTION=11;STMT=;
>
> If you omit the password from the
>   connection string then you must make
>   sure that the datasource you created
>   (AADSN) contains a password. I am not
>   going to describe what these mean, you
>   can look in the documentation for
>   myodbc for that, just ensure that you
>   get a "Connection Succeeded" message
>   when you test the datasource.

Answer (score 4):

I found this during my research on Sqlite. I haven't had the chance to use it though. Let us know if this works for you.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

> **System.Data.SQLite**   System.Data.SQLite is the original
> SQLite database engine and a complete
> ADO.NET 2.0 provider all rolled into a
> single mixed mode assembly.
>
> ...
>
> **Visual Studio 2005/2008 Design-Time
> Support**
>
> You can add a SQLite connection to the
> Server Explorer, create queries with
> the query designer, drag-and-drop
> tables onto a Typed DataSet and more!
>
> SQLite's designer works on full
> editions of Visual Studio 2005/2008,
> including VS2005 Express Editions.
>
> NEW You can create/edit views, tables, indexes, foreign keys,
> constraints and triggers interactively
> within the Visual Studio Server
> Explorer!

Comment: Too bad there's no support for design-time support (e.g. "SQLite Server Explorer" / SQLite designer) in Visual Studio 2010 :-(

Answer (score 1):

The Server Explorer should support any database system that provides an ODBC driver.  In the case of Oracle there is a built in driver with Visual Studio.

In the Add Connection Dialog click the change button on the data source you should then get a list of the providers you have drivers for.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a set of tools that integrates with Visual Studio.  It's packaged with their data access libraries.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html