# When the .net 4.0 and vs2010 beta2 will support mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

mysql server explorer cannot support vs2010 b2

who has a solution

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to browse your MySQL database, [the answers here still work in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885/does-visual-studio-server-explorer-support-custom-database-providers).